# Initialize and declare QFile

Tags: c++, qt

Can I initizialize a QFile and assign a value in a second time? I tried in this way

```
...
QFile file;
...
if (i == 0) file = QFile("foo.txt");
else file = QFile("bar.txt");
...
```

But Qt Creator rises this error: "'QFile& QFile::operator=(const QFile&)' is private within this content"

Can you help me?

Comment: Nitpick: It's the C++ compiler that signals the error, not the IDE.

Answer (score 9):

`QFile` is a `QObject`, and those are non-copyable and non-assignable. What you're looking for is the `setFileName` method:

```
QFile file;
...
file.setFileName(i == 0 ? "foo.txt" : "bar.txt");
...
```

You could also have

```
QFile file(i == 0 ? "foo.txt" : "bar.txt");
```